# Handlebars: Using @key in dot notation

Tags: handlebars.js

This should be a simple thing to do in Handlebars, but I can't seem to do it.

I have two objects:

```
a: {
  key1: "w",
  key2: "x"
}

b: {
  key1: "y",
  key2: "z"
}
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
{{#each a}}
  {{b.@key}}
{{/each}}

<!-- Should output "y z" but it doesn't! -->
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure if you can use "`@key`" in the dot notation, because every-time you try doing the same, Handlebars compilation fails.

Moreover, b is not an object present in a. So, if you're iterating over a, you can never get keys of b.

```
{{#each b}}
  {{@key}}
{{/each}}
```

This is the block of code that would iterate over "b" object, and would print all the keys present in b, meaning "y" and "z".

However, if you change your JSON to,

```
a: {
    'kx':'x',
    'ky':'y',
     b:{
      'by':'y',
      'bz':'z'
    }
}
```

then, you may get the keys of b, by saying,

```
{{#each a.b}}
   {{@key}}
{{/each}}
```

Which would  again, give you the desired result, i.e. by and bz.